# html yahoo stock not working in two DIV's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi stack overflow masters.

I have found a script that allow me to get from yahoo, stock info.
but when i use it in different DIV's only one of them work,
I have tried to fix that (not a programmer =(   ), and i dont seem to know what is the problem, and not really know how to find the solution.

code found yahoo stock for html + i have added a checker after div load run function :

```
<div class="table-box"> 
        <div class="table-detail"> 
            <img width="159px" src="http://patrickcoombe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/new-google-logo-2015.png" />
        </div>             
        <div class="table-detail"> 
            <p class="text-muted m-b-0 m-t-0">GOOGLE</p>
            <h4 class="m-t-0 m-b-5"><b><div id='GOOGstock'>$</div></b></h4> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function GOOGstock() {
                    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
                    var symbol = "GOOG";
                    var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('" + symbol + "')");

                    $.getJSON(url, 'q=' + data + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env")
                        .done(function (data) {
                        $("#GOOGstock").text("Stock Price: " + "$" + data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);
                    })
                        .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                        $("#GOOGstock").text('Request failed: ' + err);
                    });
                }

                var int=setInterval('check()', 500);
                function check()
                {
                   if (chkObject('GOOGstock')==true)
                   {
                    GOOGstock();
                   }
                }

                function chkObject(elemId)
                {
                   return (document.getElementById(elemId))? true : false;
                }
            </script>
        </div>                        
    </div>
```

Individually it workes good, but when i add another div (duplicate this script as is to other table and change GOOG to INTC stock to show 2 different stock bid prices), 
Then it works only for the one that comes last in the html code.

> Screenshot - [screenshot of the two DIV's created for yahoo stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6hpW.jpg)

how can i make it work in 1 page in different places for different stocks.
I want to make "INTC" & "GOOG" stock to show the bid price only.

thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are telling us, it seems like you haven't replaced GOOG everywhere it needs to.
Like

```
<div id='GOOGstock'>$</div></b></h4>
```

If I change this to 'INTCstock, I will need to change

```
if (chkObject('INTCstock')==true)
               {
                INTCstock();
               }
```

And

```
$("#INTCstock").text("Stock Price: " + "$" + data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);

$("#INTCstock").text('Request failed: ' + err);
```

Here is a working fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/BoyWithSilverWings/5a5r20L2/

Comment: You are correct, but its not the thing, i have changed every thing.
in the code i have 2 different top DIV, and the save code, the only difference is in one div i use "INTC" in other "GOOG"

Comment: THANK YOU A LOT :) , i will look into it and will learn what you did. you are awesom :)